# Pass args to Jar as a Service on Ubuntu

Tags: java

I have jar file running on ubuntu, its working with usb token (xml signer), and when start jar file, entering usb with pin and its take long time.

My jar file work well with following comman:

```
java -jar /opt/signinvoice.jar PIN XML_FILE
```

How can i pass arguments after run my service ?

I want pass args and sign invoice, after start service with similar command (signer.service):

```
java -jar /opt/signinvoice.jar &
```

My main class begin following command:

```
public static void main(String[] IncomingInfo) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                PIN = IncomingInfo[0];
                XmlFile = IncomingInfo[1];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken a look at [Java Command Line Args](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)?

Comment: i check some sample codes but i cant work, i am just beginner on java.

Comment: also how i will call service with args after run ?

Comment: calling the service would be a separate question and I would recommend learning some more first. That is like asking someone to show you the easy road, but their may not be. I will post an answer with a sample app you can use to learn how to take args and mess with them.

Comment: you are right its different question, i am searching its since 3 days, i am not looking easy road. but i cant find any sample..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you with parsing your args. Using `java -jar /opt/signinvoice.jar PIN XML_FILE` would give you in this application "PIN", "XML_FILE" if you were to use `System.out.printLn();` on them. So set them to what you want inside the program.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Check to make sure you have args first, we do not want an exception
        if(args.length > 0){
            String pin = args[0];
            String file = args[1];

            // Insert some args check to make sure they are what you expected, length wise, or
            // even convert to numbers

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Do stuff with args
                    PIN = pin;
                    FILE = file;
                }
            });
        } else {
            // No args oh shoot.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i modify my code with yours, getting here problem String pin = args[0]; .ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: Seeing that you have not posted much on Stackoverflow; when an answer fixes the question you can accept the answer, so that others know it fixed the problem.

Comment: thank you a lot of time mate, lets find how to pass arguments that service. thank you again

Comment: currently i am try work this jar as service on ubuntu. i will try pass arg to this service later

Comment: hi again. i added private synchronized void waitMethod() { and, jar file begin stay background. now how can pass args to runned java ?